# Android/OpenGL-ES 2.0: setDebugFlags doesn't do anything?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to utilize setDebugFlags as recommended here to scan for opengl errors:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/glsurfaceview.html

I put it in my surfaceview's constructor:

```
public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setDebugFlags(DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR | DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS);
    _renderer = new MyRenderer(getContext());
    setRenderer(_renderer);
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
}
```

Yet when running I don't see anything in verbose logcat, either under my session filter or all messages. No opengl calls, no opengl errors.

I'm manually checking for error at the end of each frame and I do have an error, but I don't know where it is coming from yet. Am I missing something obvious to get setDebugFlags to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way the wrapper works. See the [EglHelper's createSurface](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.java#GLSurfaceView.EglHelper.createSurface%28android.view.SurfaceHolder%29) method, which is the only place where `mDebugFlags` is used. It wraps the `GL10` instance and returns it. However, since you're using ES 2.0, you must use static function calls to `GLES20`, that cannot be wrapped the way it is done.

*Still* better, even if you used only GLES by calling into `GL10` instance methods, setting debug flags will [prevent you from using the extension interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969163/classcaseexception-on-gl11extensionpack-rendering-to-texture-on-opengl-android/9981109#9981109). `GL11` seems to be [totally unsupported in this regard](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5183&q=setdebugflags&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars). This bug is now over 2 years old, so better implement something yourself; [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/Overview-OpenGL-Evolution-And-JOGL.html) seems to have a nice hierarchy, however, I didn't *really* look at it, so I cannot be sure.

Comment: So, if I am reading this correctly, the debug feature simply does not work? (If you are not restricting yourself to GL ES 1)

Comment: Well, this answer is over a year and a half old. I've not looked at the implementation since then. This certainly could use a re-evaluation. Mayhaps you have a look at the [gltracer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html). It has been used successfully by a coworker.