# ClassCaseException on GL11ExtensionPack. Rendering to texture on OpenGL android

Tags: android, opengl-es, classcastexception, render-to-texture

I'm trying to render to a texture (really thought it would be easier than this!)

I found this resource: [which seems to be exactly what I want](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FrameBufferObjectActivity.html)

I'm getting a ClassCastException however, on GL11ExtensionPack gl11ep = (GL11ExtensionPack) gl;

Can anyone tell me why?

```
  public void renderToTexture(GLRenderer glRenderer, GL10 gl)
  {
    boolean checkIfContextSupportsExtension = checkIfContextSupportsExtension(gl, "GL_OES_framebuffer_object");
    if(checkIfContextSupportsExtension)
    {
      GL11ExtensionPack gl11ep = (GL11ExtensionPack) gl;

      int mFrameBuffer = createFrameBuffer(gl,texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight(), texture.getGLID());

      gl11ep.glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, mFrameBuffer);

      gl.glClearColor(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f);

      gl11ep.glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, 0);
    }
  }
```

**Issue fixed by removing** `setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS);`

However, its still not modifying the texture. I modified the code so all it does is clear the colour green, so the texture should become all green. Here is the createFrameBuffer method. I don't really understand everything thats going on in this :/

```
private int createFrameBuffer(GL10 gl, int width, int height, int targetTextureId) {
GL11ExtensionPack gl11ep = (GL11ExtensionPack) gl;
int framebuffer;
int[] framebuffers = new int[1];
gl11ep.glGenFramebuffersOES(1, framebuffers, 0);
framebuffer = framebuffers[0];
gl11ep.glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);

int depthbuffer;
int[] renderbuffers = new int[1];
gl11ep.glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, renderbuffers, 0);
depthbuffer = renderbuffers[0];

gl11ep.glBindRenderbufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthbuffer);
gl11ep.glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES,
        GL11ExtensionPack.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
gl11ep.glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,
        GL11ExtensionPack.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES,
        GL11ExtensionPack.GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthbuffer);

gl11ep.glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,
        GL11ExtensionPack.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        targetTextureId, 0);
int status = gl11ep.glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES);
if (status != GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
    //throw new RuntimeException("Framebuffer is not complete: " +
    //        Integer.toHexString(status));
  Log.v("error","Frame buffer not complete");
} else {
  gl11ep.glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, 0);
  return -1;
}
return framebuffer;
```

}

Comment: By any chance, did you `setDebugFlags` on the used `GLSurfaceView`?

Comment: Additionally, which Android version are you using?

Comment: I did, and `setDebugFlags` is still active at the moment - shall I try remving it? (at work atm, will try when I get home) I am using android version 2.3 - increased from 2.2 to see if it would work.

Comment: [they don't seem to work together](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14185) . I would never have guessed that!

Comment: Yes, I have found that issue, too ;) Did this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I am no longer getting the class cast exception. Everything seems to be working but not modifying the texture for some reason..

Comment: Please accept my answer to close your question. For the next problem: Begin from the working sample, modifying bit by bit s.t. you can check if you accidentally broke the rendering. Add calls to `glGetError` to check whether something went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setDebugFlags` on a `GLSurfaceView` to wrap the GL instance has/*had* the unfortunate sideeffect [to not implementing all `GL*` interfaces](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14185). *Unfortunately the issue does not state in which version this is fixed.*

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. Still can't get it to work though!

Comment: oh wait! everything went green and then it crashed - thats a partial success! It goes through and doesn't seem to modify the texture a few hundred times before doing it though...