# Enabling OpenGL debugging in Google Cardboard apps

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0, google-cardboard

I have recently discovered that there is a setDebugFlags method in GLSurfaceView,

[setDebugFlags(int) reference"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setDebugFlags(int))

and I would try it with my google cardboard-enabled app, yet when I enable it with:

```
cardboardView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR | GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS);
```

nothing seems to happen (well, my app might be OpenGL ES-perfect, with no errors to speak of, but why is there no OpenGL trace in `adb logcat`?).

I tried putting the call:

1. before the setRenderer
2. before the setEglContext
3. right inside the Renderer.onSurfaceCreated (with an ugly workaround to bring inside the renderer a `GLSurfaceView` reference...)
4. one second after the setRenderer initialization (because I'm a persistent bas..rd :) )

Logs are enabled (I can see everything up to the "debug" level), and the app, works fine, otherwise.

Any help finding out what's happening would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a similar question from a couple of years ago here:
[Android/OpenGL-ES 2.0: setDebugFlags doesn't do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658863/android-opengl-es-2-0-setdebugflags-doesnt-do-anything)

Says that getting it to work is tricky, although I'd be surprised if nothing has changed in that time.

But embedded in a comment was a link to another too that might be useful, called GLTracer:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html

Comment: Thank you! I knew about GLTracer, which btw now is invoked with the command `monitor` in the sdk tools (problem is, I can't use it to get feedback from my users...), but I missed the SO post you linked.